# How can I represent one column's values using multiple columns in R where one new column is conditional?

Tags: r, dplyr

Looking at similar questions, I could not find one that matched my need.
If one does contain a solution, please share its link.

I have this dput-produced data:

```
structure(list(Player = c("Seth Lugo", "Jacob deGrom", "Rick Porcello", 
"David Peterson", "Michael Wacha", "Seth Lugo", "Jacob deGrom", 
"Rick Porcello", "David Peterson", "Steven Matz", "Seth Lugo", 
"Jacob deGrom", "Rick Porcello", "David Peterson", "Seth Lugo", 
"Jacob deGrom", "Rick Porcello", "Michael Wacha", "David Peterson", 
"Jacob deGrom", "Seth Lugo", "Rick Porcello", "Robert Gsellman", 
"Michael Wacha", "Ariel Jurado", "Jacob deGrom", "Rick Porcello", 
"Seth Lugo", "Robert Gsellman", "David Peterson"), Date = structure(c(1601164800, 
1601078400, 1601078400, 1600905600, 1600819200, 1600732800, 1600646400, 
1600560000, 1600473600, 1600387200, 1600300800, 1600214400, 1600128000, 
1599955200, 1599868800, 1599782400, 1599609600, 1599523200, 1599436800, 
1599350400, 1599264000, 1599177600, 1599091200, 1599004800, 1598918400, 
1598832000, 1598745600, 1598745600, 1598659200, 1598572800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), DblHdr = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2), DateStr = c("09/27/2020", 
"09/26/2020", "09/26/2020", "09/24/2020", "09/23/2020", "09/22/2020", 
"09/21/2020", "09/20/2020", "09/19/2020", "09/18/2020", "09/17/2020", 
"09/16/2020", "09/15/2020", "09/13/2020", "09/12/2020", "09/11/2020", 
"09/09/2020", "09/08/2020", "09/07/2020", "09/06/2020", "09/05/2020", 
"09/04/2020", "09/03/2020", "09/02/2020", "09/01/2020", "08/31/2020", 
"08/30/2020", "08/30/2020", "08/29/2020", "08/28/2020"), Month = c("09", 
"09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", 
"09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", 
"09", "09", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08"), Tm = c("NYM", "NYM", 
"NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", 
"NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", 
"NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", 
"NYM"), Opp = c("WSN", "WSN", "WSN", "WSN", "TBR", "TBR", "TBR", 
"ATL", "ATL", "ATL", "PHI", "PHI", "PHI", "TOR", "TOR", "TOR", 
"BAL", "BAL", "PHI", "PHI", "PHI", "PHI", "NYY", "BAL", "BAL", 
"MIA", "NYY", "NYY", "NYY", "NYY"), Rslt = c("L 5-15", "L 3-4", 
"L 3-5", "W 3-2", "L 5-8", "W 5-2", "L 1-2", "L 0-7", "W 7-2", 
"L 2-15", "W 10-6", "W 5-4", "L 1-4", "L 3-7", "L 2-3", "W 18-1", 
"W 7-6", "L 2-11", "L 8-9", "W 14-1", "W 5-1", "L 3-5", "W 9-7", 
"W 9-4", "L 5-9", "L 3-5", "L 7-8", "L 2-5", "L 1-2", "W 4-3"
), W_L = c("L", "L", "L", "W", "L", "W", "L", "L", "W", "L", 
"W", "W", "L", "L", "L", "W", "W", "L", "L", "W", "W", "L", "W", 
"W", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "W"), temp = c("L 5", "L 3", "L 3", 
"W 3", "L 5", "W 5", "L 1", "L 0", "W 7", "L 2", "W 10", "W 5", 
"L 1", "L 3", "L 2", "W 18", "W 7", "L 2", "L 8", "W 14", "W 5", 
"L 3", "W 9", "W 9", "L 5", "L 3", "L 7", "L 2", "L 1", "W 4"
), RS = c(5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 1, 0, 7, 2, 10, 5, 1, 3, 2, 18, 7, 
2, 8, 14, 5, 3, 9, 9, 5, 3, 7, 2, 1, 4), RA = c(15, 4, 5, 2, 
8, 2, 2, 7, 2, 15, 6, 4, 4, 7, 3, 1, 6, 11, 9, 1, 1, 5, 7, 4, 
9, 5, 8, 5, 2, 3), Rdiff = c(-10, -1, -2, 1, -3, 3, -1, -7, 5, 
-13, 4, 1, -3, -4, -1, 17, 1, -9, -1, 13, 4, -2, 2, 5, -4, -2, 
-1, -3, -1, 1), absV = c(10, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 7, 5, 13, 4, 1, 
3, 4, 1, 17, 1, 9, 1, 13, 4, 2, 2, 5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1), App_Dec = c("GS-2, L", 
"GS-5", "GS-3, L", "GS-7, W", "GS-6, L", "GS-7, W", "GS-7, L", 
"GS-7, L", "GS-6, W", "GS-3, L", "GS-2", "GS-2", "GS-6, L", "GS-5, L", 
"GS-6, L", "GS-6, W", "GS-4", "GS-4, L", "GS-2", "GS-7, W", "GS-5, W", 
"GS-6", "GS-2", "GS-3", "GS-4", "GS-6, L", "GS-5", "GS-4", "GS-4", 
"GS-4"), IP = c(1.1, 5, 3, 7, 6, 6.1, 7, 7, 6, 2.2, 1.2, 2, 6, 
5, 5.1, 6, 4, 4, 2, 7, 5, 6, 1.2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 3.2, 4, 4), H = c(5, 
5, 8, 4, 6, 4, 4, 3, 3, 8, 8, 4, 6, 3, 7, 3, 10, 7, 3, 3, 4, 
3, 4, 4, 9, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4), R = c(6, 3, 5, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
6, 6, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3
), ER = c(6, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 6, 6, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 5, 
4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3), BB = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 0, 2, 
2, 2, 0, 3), SO = c(1, 10, 3, 4, 4, 7, 14, 10, 10, 5, 3, 1, 5, 
2, 5, 9, 3, 3, 3, 12, 8, 6, 0, 2, 2, 9, 2, 7, 4, 3), HR = c(0, 
2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), UER = c(0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Pit = c(38, 113, 67, 107, 66, 95, 112, 100, 102, 76, 52, 
    40, 94, 81, 91, 102, 66, 71, 70, 108, 81, 100, 52, 69, 84, 
    103, 86, 60, 57, 70), Str = c(24, 78, 42, 68, 45, 66, 70, 
    70, 62, 45, 30, 25, 66, 52, 60, 68, 45, 49, 37, 74, 50, 65, 
    22, 41, 53, 72, 55, 39, 33, 37), GSc = c(19, 53, 29, 68, 
    48, 65, 73, 75, 68, 20, 18, 36, 47, 53, 46, 69, 25, 33, 29, 
    77, 61, 62, 27, 44, 26, 57, 51, 54, 54, 42), BF = c(12, 22, 
    19, 26, 23, 24, 26, 26, 24, 18, 14, 11, 26, 20, 24, 23, 21, 
    20, 14, 26, 21, 23, 13, 15, 21, 27, 20, 16, 15, 18), AB = c(8, 
    20, 18, 24, 23, 23, 23, 23, 20, 15, 13, 9, 24, 18, 22, 21, 
    21, 20, 9, 24, 19, 21, 8, 13, 20, 25, 18, 14, 15, 15), H2B = c(2, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0), H3B = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0), IBB = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
    HBP = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SH = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SF = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), GDP = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), SB = c(0, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0), CS = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), PO = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BK = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), WP = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0), ERA = c("40.5", "5.4", "9", "1.29", "6", "1.42", 
    "2.57", "1.29", "1.5", "20.25", "32.4", "13.5", "6", "3.6", 
    "5.0599999999999996", "1.5", "11.25", "9", "22.5", "1.29", 
    "1.8", "3", "21.6", "6", "11.25", "1.5", "3.6", "2.4500000000000002", 
    "2.25", "6.75"), WPA = c(-0.471, -0.087, -0.256, 0.34, -0.22, 
    0.18, 0.107, 0.219, 0.229, -0.358, -0.487, -0.186, -0.156, 
    0.036, -0.047, 0.049, -0.329, -0.321, -0.34, 0.193, 0.156, 
    0.07, -0.312, -0.042, -0.278, -0.271, 0.029, 0.02, 0.092, 
    -0.174), RE24 = c(-5.122, -0.193, -3.316, 2.931, -1.08, 1.509, 
    1.406, 2.406, 1.92, -4.641, -5.444, -1.919, -0.758, 0.679, 
    0.245, 2.215, -3.054, -3.054, -4.027, 2.406, 1.433, 0.92, 
    -3.788, -0.359, -2.812, -1.08, 0.707, 0.364, 1.166, -0.834
    ), aLI = c(1.45, 1.244, 0.974, 1.271, 0.965, 0.921, 0.955, 
    0.888, 1.066, 0.962, 0.767, 1.073, 0.941, 0.852, 1.353, 0.392, 
    0.857, 0.805, 0.904, 0.75, 1.037, 0.861, 1.232, 1.355, 0.914, 
    1.239, 1.213, 1.28, 0.748, 1.407)), row.names = c(NA, -30L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Desired output:

The numbers starting in the second column are the total absV values for each player for each column. The last column contains the sum of all the absV values for each player where absV > 5. Only a sample of the first 3 rows are shown, and the absV values are just filler numbers.

```
| Player | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | >5 |
| deGrom | 2 | 3 | 5 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| Matz | 2 | 3 | 5 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
```

Code tried (I need help getting beyond the point shown). I would prefer if the code uses dplyr:

```
starter %>%
  select(Player, absV) %>%
  group_by(Player, absV) %>%
  summarize(numG= n()) %>%
  arrange(Player,absV)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you to bifurcate your data with `rows` per player `>5` and `<=5`, then `rbind` them together and thereafter `pivot_wider`.  Follow this code

```
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr) 

df <- starter %>% group_by(Player) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  select(Player, absV, row) %>% arrange(Player) 

df %>% filter(row <= 5) %>% 
  mutate(row = as.character(row)) %>%
  rbind(df %>% filter(row > 5) %>% 
          summarise( absV = sum(absV))  %>% 
          mutate(row = ">5")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Player, names_from = row, values_from = absV)

# A tibble: 8 x 7
# Groups:   Player [8]
  Player            `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`  `>5`
  <chr>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Ariel Jurado        4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2 David Peterson      1     5     4     1     1    NA
3 Jacob deGrom        1     1     1    17    13     2
4 Michael Wacha       3     9     5    NA    NA    NA
5 Rick Porcello       2     7     3     1     2     1
6 Robert Gsellman     2     1    NA    NA    NA    NA
7 Seth Lugo          10     3     4     1     4     3
8 Steven Matz        13    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Note. Loading `tidyverse` package, at once, directly is advised.

**Note-2** If you still want to sort absV before changing the data-format, add absV in arrange syntax beforehand joining them..

```
df <- starter %>% group_by(Player) %>% 
  arrange(Player, absV) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  select(Player, absV, row) 

df %>% filter(row <= 5) %>% 
  mutate(row = as.character(row)) %>%
  rbind(df %>% filter(row > 5) %>% 
          summarise( absV = sum(absV))  %>% 
          mutate(row = ">5")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Player, names_from = row, values_from = absV)

#this will give the following diff output

# A tibble: 8 x 7
# Groups:   Player [8]
  Player            `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`  `>5`
  <chr>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Ariel Jurado        4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2 David Peterson      1     1     1     4     5    NA
3 Jacob deGrom        1     1     1     2    13    17
4 Michael Wacha       3     5     9    NA    NA    NA
5 Rick Porcello       1     1     2     2     3     7
6 Robert Gsellman     1     2    NA    NA    NA    NA
7 Seth Lugo           1     3     3     4     4    10
8 Steven Matz        13    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

## Additional Question in comments below

Follow this code to work out frequency of each absV

```
df %>% group_by(Player, absV) %>% mutate(freq = n()) %>% ungroup()

#check it
df %>% group_by(Player, absV) %>% mutate(freq = n()) %>% ungroup() %>% select(Player, absV, freq)
   Player          absV  freq
   <chr>          <dbl> <int>
 1 Seth Lugo         10     1
 2 Jacob deGrom       1     3
 3 Rick Porcello      2     2
 4 David Peterson     1     3
 5 Michael Wacha      3     1
 6 Seth Lugo          3     2
 7 Jacob deGrom       1     3
 8 Rick Porcello      7     1
 9 David Peterson     5     1
10 Steven Matz       13     1
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Comment: I only need seven columns. 

In the seventh column, the one whose name is ">5", I need the total of all the columns containing the absV values from 6 until the highest one, which I think is 44.

Comment: see the edited answer together with explanation of code

Comment: Did it serve the purpose?

Comment: AnilGoyal, that helps a lot. How much would the code change if I wanted for each player just a count showing how many times each absV value (e.g., 1, 2, 3 etc.) appears? For example, for Seth Lugo the absV value of 3 occurs three different times while for Jacob deGrom, the absV value of 4 occurs eight times. (If that is a question for a different post, I understand.)

Comment: see edited answer.  Please accept and upvote as usually desired on SO for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(starter), Player ~ rowid(Player), value.var = 'absV')
```

Comment: Please see previous comment.

Comment: akron: I only need seven columns. In the seventh column, the one whose name is ">5", I need the total of all the columns containing the absV values from 6 until the highest one, which I think is 44.